# Eclipse content assist, only confirm suggestion on return

Tags: eclipse

When using the content assist in Eclipse, is there any way you can configure it so that the suggestion is only inserted if you hit return?

For example when I declare a new variable it wants to extend the name with the class name and if I don't want this for the current variable I have to use escape. I have tried adjusting the activation delay and it solves the problem in some situations, but I would much rather confirm all suggestions with return. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Content assist is related to the current used editor and its configuration is editor specific, Java editor activates Content Assist by default and automatically when you type the dot, otherwise you have to call it through <kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

If i well understood you are struggling with the automatic activation of Content assist, if so you can deactivate it from :

```
Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist (Auto Activation section)
```

It is not possible to change the behaviour of Content Assist since it is directly managed by the editor itself, so the better work around for you would be deactivate Auto Activation and call it with the shortcut when needed.